# Can Firedac handle conditional SQL statements

Tags: delphi, firedac

Is there a way to use `Firedac` to handle conditional scenarios.

Master Table has a column called INVOICESCOUNT.

When an invoice is deleted successfully, then the INVOICESCOUNT is decreased.

For example, a SQL psuedo-code statement like this:

```
Delete From Invoices where INVOICE=500;
Update Customers SET INVOICECOUNT=INVOICECOUNT-1 WHERE Customer=1  (if prior statement returns 1 affected row);
```

I need it to be embedded within the same SQL statement instead of having the Delphi source code handling executing the 2 statements separately, after the first FDQuery returns a successful execution.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What's wrong with executing the statements separately? If you want to avoid problems keeping them in sync, put the statements inside of a transaction, or even a stored procedure.

Comment: The code will be on server... so it will be a chunk of transactions going in at any one time.  will be hosting this on AWS or Azure hosted mysql service eventually, so I thought it'll be more efficient to send 10 SQL statements (5 groups of 2 sql lines), rather than executing 10 SQL queries to update 5 invoice deletes (from 5 different customers).

Comment: Does a `Customer` field exist in the `Invoices` table? If so, then have you considered using a `DELETE TRIGGER` on the `Invoices` table? Whenever a record is being deleted from `Invoices`, the trigger could extract the `Customer` of the `Old` record and then `UPDATE` the `Customers` table accordingly. That way, your code won't have to `UPDATE` the `Customers` table manually at all, only `DELETE` the `Invoices` records, the `UPDATE` would be done automatically.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Thanks for the suggestion.  The only Customer field is CustomerID in Invoices table.  oh noted, I could use the `TRIGGER` for deletes, but I also have cases whereby an edit on some field the Invoice field, will need to update the Customer table as well.

Comment: triggers work for inserts and updates, too. You are given access to the old and new records, so you can check for specific field changes as needed and act accordingly

Comment: ok noted with much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's fine ?

I understood, lack of attention from me, in this case I could use the information from the DBMS itself, an example, if the DBMS is SQL server.

```sql
Delete From Invoices where INVOICE=500    
IF @@ROWCOUNT=1
begin
  Update Customers SET INVOICECOUNT=INVOICECOUNT-1
  WHERE Customer=1
end.
```

If your DBMS doesn't allow it, I recommend you to use a stored procedure.

Comment: The OP specifically stated in their question that they DON'T want to execute multiple SQL statements separately like this.

Comment: Ok, has been Adjusted.

Comment: In SQL SERVER it is also a statement, it is part of the query.

Comment: @JoaoBoscodosReisBecker Thank you! If it can be executed in a single TFDQuery, it is acceptable, as long as it doesn't require me to check if FDQuery1.RowsAffected=1 then {... execute 2nd part of query } again...

Comment: I suppose the equivalent will be using IF SELECT ROW_COUNT()=1 ... in MySQL